# SVG | y-coordinate is different

Tags: svg, inkscape

The svg file: http://pastebin.com/8N61VpS1

[image]

```
<rect
   style="fill:#000000"
   id="rect3409"
   width="166.39345"
   height="180.32787"
   x="77.049179"
   y="611.37854" />
```

The rectangle "rect3409" has coordinates (x,y) = (77.049, 260.656) in Inkscape 0.91 r13725.

However, the tag `<rect>` with id `rect3409` has (x, y) = (77.049, 611.379). Why are there differences between the two?

I want to get the correct SVG coordinate of the rectangle. How do I do that?

Comment: The svg xml file is attached, please take a look. I'm new to svg and inkscape.

Comment: Inkscape has its own coordinate system that is entirely separate from the SVG coordinates. Which of these are the "correct" coordinates you're trying to find?

Comment: The SVG coordinates. I'll edit the question then.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage that doesn't sound right to me, do you have a reference for that? One issue I've found in getting co-ords out of Inkscape is that it tends to put elements inside groups with `transform`s, so for example the `x` attribute on the `rect` is not the final position, you need to combine all the transforms on all the nested groups back to the parent `svg` element.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage on second thoughts: do you mean that Inkscape puts `y = 0` at the bottom of the image, and increases `y` going up the screen, while SVGs usually have `y = 0` at the top, and increasing `y` going down the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source, you'll see that `#rect3409` has a parent `g` element:

```
<g transform="translate(0,-452.36216)">
  <!-- snip -->
  <rect
    id="rect3409"
    width="166.39345"
    height="180.32787"
    x="77.049179"
    y="611.37854" />
</g>
```

The `transform=translate(tx, ty)` attribute on the `g` is applied to the dimensions of `#rect3409`. So the vertical axis of the `rect` goes from `y + ty` to `y + h + ty`, which is `611 - 452 == 159px` to `611 + 180 - 452 == 339px`. **I think these are the "correct SVG co-ordinate" values you want.**

But Inkscape is not reporting these values, but rather `261px` to `441px`. It seems like Inkscape is actually flipping the `y` axis: in SVG (and conventionally in all computer graphics) `y=0` is at the top of the screen, and `y` increases as you move *down* the screen. For example, the following SVG displays a red box above a blue box:

```
<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="red" />
  <rect x="0" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

In Inkscape, however, you have the mathematical convention of `y=0` at the bottom, and `y` increasing as you go upwards. Therefore, the co-ordinates you see in Inkscape are modified from the "true" SVG co-ordinates (thanks @squeamish ossifrage for pointing this out in the comments): `y_Inkscape = h_image - y_SVG`, where `y_Inkscape` is what Inkscape tells, you, `y_SVG` is what's in the file, and `h_image` is the total image height.

Your sample image is exactly 600px high, so the "Inkscape" co-ordinates of `#rect3409` are
 `600 - 339 == 261px`, and
 `600 - 159 == 441px`.